# How to find area between curves? ($\frac{1}{x}$ problem)

Tags: definite-integrals, area

I need to find the area between those curves:
$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $f(x)=6e^x$, $f(x)=1$, $f(x)=6$

I calculated the limits of integration, it is $\ln(\frac{1}{6})$ to $1$.
But we cannot integrate through this interval, since the sign changes and $\frac{1}{x}$ is not defined for zero. How to find area in this case?

[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ngsfp855ih)(I added inequality for colored the target area)

[image: area]

Comment: Do the regions $[\ln(\frac{1}{6}),0],[0,\frac{1}{6}]$ and $[\frac{1}{6},1]$ in different cases.

Comment: This is a "Type 2" or "y-simple" region.  Integrate with respect to $y$ and the bounds are much easier.

Comment: @B.Goddard Just write it as answer(for accepting)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to consider $x$ as a function of $y$ in each case.

But to proceed your way, note that you have to split the integral into three parts, to get $$\int_{-\log 6}^0 (6e^x -1)dx+\int_0^{1/6} (6-1)dx+\int_{1/6}^1 \left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right) dx.$$